# Limiting community member communication in PVLAN's

Tags: access-control, private-vlan

Is there a way to limit communication between community members in a PVLAN?

Ex.
Service provider ABC has 1000 clients, the clients with more than one VM to their name have their own community, however the provider wants only specific ports to talk across the VM's within that community.

If there is a way please explain how it would work!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Private VLANS are a layer 2 technology.  To filter specific ports, you need something that operates at layer 4.  There are virtualized firewalls that would be applied per VM that could do this for you.

Comment: Hey Ron,  Sorry for the delay in response.  Ok, and that's easy enough to work with - to confirm there is no built in (cisco) way to filter intra-community traffic?  I will mark answer after confirmation - thanks again!